# Asynchronous requests in loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I want to implement the status log in textarea feature in my WordPress plugin. So I have a PHP variable which constantly updates and I want it to be displayed in the textarea in the admin panel.
I've tried to make a loop in JavaScript which asks server for changes of the variable every second, but as PHP is executing in blocking manner the server just ignores the request.

Comment: Can you please share the sample code?

Comment: Please explain your feature too. what should do the front and the admin clearly ?

Comment: I never used it myself, but this seems like a use case for the [Heartbeat API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/heartbeat-api/).

Comment: @Michael it seem to be a good library for long polling in WP yes. The best for realtime is websocket IMO, but it's not so easy to setup

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a function in your backend who gets all the information and return a HTML object and call this function using Javascript or whatever you wanna use for this call, after you get this html, just update the view.

Or if you prefer using Javascript, rather than returning a HTML, just return all data that you wanna show and update the view :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like sort of "live updates", so when a new log message appears in PHP, it will show up in the textarea immediately.

Comment: You could push the changes to some sort of API method (`mysite.org/listener/update/`) and then use Javascript to update your textarea, instead of querying your server to check for changes.

Comment: Try to insert a loop in your javascript (setInterval) which calls the javascript function which calls the PHP function.